# How to set the validation rules using a setter method in Laravel?

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

I need to set the `$rules` array in the Validator Class using a setter method.

I need to set defined the $rules using a setter because the rules are stored in a database. I need to use Eloquent to query the database to figure out what will the rules look like.

I extended the Validator Class and added a method called setCustomRules(). I injected a class into this method which will allow me to use Eloquent to read the database to determine the rules.

But, how would I force the setCustomRules() method to fire when Laravel attempt to validate? This method must take place first to ensure that the rules are set before the validation takes place.

This is what I have done

```
<?php namespace Vend\Surveys\Validator\SurveyAnswers;

use Cartalyst\Support\Validator;

use Vend\Surveys\Repositories\SurveyAnswers\SurveyAnswerDefinedRepository;

class SurveyAnswerDefinedValidator extends Validator implements SurveyAnswerDefinedValidatorInterface {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected $rules;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function onUpdate()
    {

    }


    public function setCustomRules(SurveyAnswerDefinedRepository $rules)
    {

        foreach($rules as $rule){
            $this->rules[$rule->name] = $rule->spec;
        }

        //this should display the rules that will be used to validate the form
        dd($this->rules);
    }


}
```

**Edited**
Based on The Alpha's answer, I created an Event Handler that will let me create the rules. But not sure how to tell Laravel to validate now.

This is my EventHandler class

```
<?php namespace vend\Surveys\Handlers\SurveyAnswers;

use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
use vend\Surveys\Models\SurveyAnswerDefined;
use Cartalyst\Support\Handlers\EventHandler as BaseEventHandler;

use vend\Surveys\Repositories\SurveyQuestions\SurveyQuestionsRepositoryInterface;

class SurveyAnswerDefinedEventHandler extends BaseEventHandler implements SurveyAnswerDefinedEventHandlerInterface {

    protected $rules = [];
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function subscribe(Dispatcher $dispatcher)
    {
        $dispatcher->listen('vend.surveys.surveyanswerdefined.creating', __CLASS__.'@creating');
        $dispatcher->listen('vend.surveys.surveyanswerdefined.created', __CLASS__.'@created');

        $dispatcher->listen('vend.surveys.surveyanswerdefined.updating', __CLASS__.'@updating');
        $dispatcher->listen('vend.surveys.surveyanswerdefined.updated', __CLASS__.'@updated');

        $dispatcher->listen('vend.surveys.surveyanswerdefined.deleted', __CLASS__.'@deleted');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function creating(SurveyQuestionsRepositoryInterface $questions, array $data)
    {
        $this->setRules($questions);
        dd($this->rules);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function created(SurveyAnswerDefined $surveyanswers)
    {
        $this->flushCache($surveyanswers);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function updating(SurveyAnswerDefined $surveyanswers, array $data)
    {

        $this->setRules($questions);
        dd($this->rules);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function updated(SurveyAnswerDefined $surveyanswers)
    {
        $this->flushCache($surveyanswers);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function deleted(SurveyAnswerDefined $surveyanswers)
    {
        $this->flushCache($surveyanswers);
    }

    /**
     * Flush the cache.
     *
     * @param  \vend\Surveys\Models\Surveyanswers  $surveyanswers
     * @return void
     */
    protected function flushCache(SurveyAnswerDefined $surveyanswers)
    {
        $this->app['cache']->forget('vend.surveys.surveyanswerdefined.all');

        $this->app['cache']->forget('vend.surveys.surveyanswerdefined.'.$surveyanswers->id);
    }


    private function setRules($questions){

        foreach($questions as $question){

            foreach($questions->controls as $control){

                $this->rules['control_' . $control->id] = $this->makeRules($control);
            }

        }
    }

    private function makeRules($control){

        $rules = [];

        if($control->is_required){
            $rules[] = 'required';
        }

        if($control->validation_rule == 'Text'){

            if($control->min_length){
                $rules[] = 'min:' . $control->max_length;
            }

            if($control->max_length){
                $rules[] = 'max:' . $control->max_length;
            }

        }


        if($control->validation_rule == 'Number'){

            $rules[] = 'numeric';

            if($control->min_value){
                $rules[] = 'min:' . $control->max_length;
            }

            if($control->max_value){
                $rules[] = 'max:' . $control->max_length;
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**late answer**

You can also use [Model Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) and validate

e.g.

```
public function setFirstNameAttribute($value) {
    // validate $value e.g.:
    if (strlen($value) < 2) {
        throw new \Exception('name too short, 2 char minimum');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can (IMO) utilize the model events, for example: when saving (Applies to create & Updated) you may call the `setCustomRules` method to set and validate rules using something like this:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    // This method will be called on creating and updating
    // but there are separate events for both methods so you
    // may use separate handlers for different events like : 
    // static::creating(...) static::updating(...)
    static::saving(function($user)
    {
        // Set rules and validate here
    });
}
```

This should be in the Model and there are other ways to register events but I prefer this way most. For more information, check [Laravel Website@Events](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events)

Comment: If I understand the request lifecycle in laravel http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/lifecycle, the validation step takes place before any database operations. so if there are error Laravel will generate error and then send the user to the view or what every is being returned to the controller's method. So if the validation takes place before any SQL operation, your suggestion will lead to validation twice once the default Laravel step and then the step before saving. What am I missing here?

Comment: No, if you register those events then it'll work like that way. For example, in the boot method if you register a `creating(function(){...})` then before the new model is created the function will be executed. If you return false from that function then create will be interrupted, mean won't save the new model for invalid data. You need to catch that manually.

Comment: I think I get it. Then how will I inject SurveyAnswerDefinedRepository class into the saving() event so I can read the rules in the database?

Comment: Pass the rules to that model or fetch the rules from within the model itself, just try it, read the doc for more information, I believe you'll be able to do it :-)

Comment: I think I follow you. well I hope I am :)   I created creating, updating event handlers and I injected the class that will allow me to get the rules. How to I set the rules or tell Laravel to validate now? I mean how would I trigger the validator?  I will update my question with my code